# Can the istio log output time zone be modified?

Tags: time, timezone, istio

```
[2020-11-27T03:53:09.046Z] "HEAD /productpage HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 0 27 27 "10.244.11.0" "curl/7.47.0" "ef48c206-422a-9d0d-ac56-9be531b190f7" "10.22.24.5:31695" "10.244.6.18:9080" outbound|9080||productpage.istio-web.svc.cluster.local 10.244.6.251:41376 10.244.6.251:8080 10.244.11.0:54697 - -
```

How to change istio log time zone to 'Asia/Shanghai'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic has already been discussed on envoy github as istio uses [envoy access log](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage#access-logging).

As far as I know currently it's not possible. There are github issues I mentioned above about that which says that it's designed in **UTC** by default.

- [Access log's timestamps are still in UTC regardless a containter's timezone](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/3546)
- [How to change the log time zone of each component of Istio to CST format](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22582)

It's not even possible to persuade the image to use your timezone as envoy will use the UTC anyway.